# Reshape JSON hierarchically

Tags: python, json, treeview

I have this JSON file:

```
{
    "animal": {
        "debug": {
            "forceQuitCell": true,
            "surviveWithoutFood": false
        },
        "name": "Tyrannosaurus_sp",
        "defaultHuntingMode": "active_hunting",
        "sexualType": "diploid",
        "size": 1,
...
```

It is being read in Python by:

```
dict = json.load("myjson.file")
```

Then I parse it into a TreeView resulting in what you see on the image:

[image]

The problem with indentation is obvious. For example, name -> Tyrannosaurus_sp should lie under animal and not under debug.

Reading docs it seems this is the natural way of loading a json and showing it if you populate the TreeView in order (you insert as you read items from dictionary).

Question is, is there a way to reorder the JSON so it "makes sense" and is perfectly ordered hierarchically? I have not found a way. Another approach would be to create a new insertion method that stores all items with their related parent and the go and insert in order by parent.

Any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: The argument to `json.load()` is not a filename, it's an open file stream.

Comment: Please show your code that creates the TreeView? But I think this should probably be closed as a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57036493/create-tkinter-nested-treeview-from-nested-dictionary